# Celery sqlite result database not being created w/ Django, rabbitmq, & sqlalchemy

Tags: django, sqlite, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, celery

I have `Celery` set up with `Django`. I'm using `RabbitMQ` as my broker. I'm trying to set up `sqlalchemy` as my result back-end with a `sqlite` database separate from the `Django` database. I have `RabbitMQ`, `Django`, & `Celery` all running without any issues. I put in my `settings.py` `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///celery_results.sqlite3'` & on `Celery` worker startup it shows the back-end configured correctly in the log output.

The problem is that my database isn't being created. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will save someone some head scratching or ruining their configuration. Everything was set up correctly and running fine. The issue was that I didn't have any tasks running since I wanted as little going on as possible during setup. Once I ran a task the `sqlite` database & tables were created successfully. I was also able to write a script to confirm that the task results were being stored in the database.